# Checkbox array in form array

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

I am trying to get the array of checkboxes within a form array. I am trying to get the data as the form array first then get the array of checkboxes within the array.

```
<form name="preview" id="post" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="category[$id]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="something" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="somewhere" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="something" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="somewhere" />

    <input type="hidden" name="category[$id]" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="something" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="somewhere" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="something" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="somewhere" />
    <input class="button-primary" name="submit_preview" value="Submit Selected Tees" type="submit">
</form>
if (isset($_POST['submit_preview'])) {
    foreach ( $_POST[ 'category' ] as $id ) {
        foreach ( $_POST[ 'subcat' ][$id] as $subcat ) {
             echo $subcat;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .....And the problem is??

Comment: the problem is there is no question mark in the question

Comment: Downvoted for lack of question.

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Mindreading: You get all checkbox-values across all categories but want them by category.
--> you have to link the subcategories (checkboxes) to the categories by the name-attribute.

`$categories`: array holding `id` and `name` of your categories:

```
<form name="preview" id="post" action="" method="post">
<?
foreach ($categories as $cat) { // for each of your categories 4 checkboxes

    echo "<p>category: {$cat['name']}</p>";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cat_{$cat['id']}_sub[]\" value=\"something\" /> option 1<br />";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cat_{$cat['id']}_sub[]\" value=\"something\" /> option 2<br />";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cat_{$cat['id']}_sub[]\" value=\"something\" /> option 3<br />";
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cat_{$cat['id']}_sub[]\" value=\"something\" /> option 4<br />";
    // name of checkbox if id=1: "cat_1_sub[]"

} // foreach

<input class="button-primary" name="submit_preview" value="Submit Selected Tees" type="submit">
</form>
```

After submit:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_preview'])) {

    foreach ( $_POST as $name => $value) {

        if (substr($name,0,4)=='cat_') echo "$name: $value <br />";

    } // foreach
} // if isset
```